# How to connect the oauth2 client for using the services of google sheets API in my google cloud virtual machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I created one web application in Flask and hosted in google cloud instance for using the API of google drive and google sheet I created the credentions google client APi using oauth2 . For redirecting the url to login I pointed the IP address of the virtual machine now It when I call the Ip address of my virtual machine the Ip It says raw address are not allowed. Can you guys help me to solve this issue. I

The error it raise is

Error 400: invalid_request
Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Raw IP addresses not allowed

Comment: What's your IP? Do you have piece of code to share?

Comment: no. The ip address is the IP of hosts